# IOS Button touch up inside - First touch = Action1 and second touch = Action2// loop between the two

Tags: ios, swift, button, action

> Hi all
>
> I have attached below code. Upon launch, the view controller displays
>   a logo in the center and four main user buttons on the bottom.I try to
>   achieve that if the first button got touched up inside (Called Lists),
>   the logo fades and the center circle displays the name (Lists) of the
>   first button and shows around it buttons with different submenu
>   points, in the same time the 4 main (initial) buttons fade and are
>   only seen at a minimal (low Alpha). I want to achieve that if the
>   faded (half visible)main button gets touched again initial view is
>   restored with logo and only the main four menu buttons. Meaning, first
>   touch shows sub menus and its animations and second click returns to
>   initial view. Again clicked shows again submenu and so on. How can i
>   do that?
>
> Thanks Dnai

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  NanCom1
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 8/13/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Daniel Habshush. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView* logo;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* button4;


@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* listMain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* shoppingList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* todoList;




@end

//
//  ViewController.m
//  NanCom1
//
//  Created by Daniel Habshush on 8/13/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Daniel Habshush. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    UIDynamicAnimator* _animator;
    UIGravityBehavior* _gravity;
    UICollisionBehavior* _collision;

}


@synthesize logo, button1, button2, button3, button4, listMain, todoList, shoppingList;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    logo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage *logoPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo3.png"];
    logo.image=logoPic;
    logo.frame = CGRectMake(100, 200, 175, 175);
    [logo setAlpha:0];
    [self.view addSubview:logo];


    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [UIImageView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIImageView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.logo.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIImageView commitAnimations];



    button1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];

     [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 90, 90)];


    [button1 setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];

    button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Lists" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [button1 setEnabled:YES];


    [self.view addSubview:button1];




    button2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 2, 90, 90)];
    [button2 setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
    button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2 setTitle:@"Cirlce" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button2.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [button2 setEnabled:YES];

    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:button2];





    button3 = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 2, 90, 90)];

    button3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3 setTitle:@"Location" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button3.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [button3 setEnabled:YES];

     [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button3];


    button4 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 2, 90, 90)];

    button4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [button4 setTitle:@"Menu" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button4.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [button4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [button4 setEnabled:YES];

     [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed4:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button4];





    _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    _gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button1, button2, button3, button4]];
    [_animator addBehavior:_gravity];


    _collision = [[UICollisionBehavior alloc]
                  initWithItems:@[button1, button2, button3, button4]];

    _collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = YES;



    [_animator addBehavior:_collision];



    UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour4 = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button4]];
    itemBehaviour4.elasticity = 0.4;
    itemBehaviour4.resistance = 0.65;

    [_animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour4];


    UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour3 = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button3]];
    itemBehaviour3.elasticity = 0.45;
    itemBehaviour3.resistance = 0.5;

    [_animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour3];



    UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour2 = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button2]];
    itemBehaviour2.elasticity = 0.5;
    itemBehaviour2.resistance = 0.3;
    [_animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour2];

    UIDynamicItemBehavior* itemBehaviour1 = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[button1]];
    itemBehaviour1.elasticity = 0.37;
    itemBehaviour1.resistance = 0.2;

    [_animator addBehavior:itemBehaviour1];
}


- (void)pressed:(UIButton*)button1 {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button1.alpha = 0.3;
    self.button2.alpha = 0.3;
    self.button3.alpha = 0.3;
    self.button4.alpha = 0.3;


    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.logo.alpha = 0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    listMain = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [listMain setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 175, 175)];

    listMain.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [listMain setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listMain setTitle:@"Lists" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [listMain.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:35]];

    [listMain setAlpha:0];


    [self.view addSubview:listMain];


    todoList = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [todoList setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 145, 75, 75)];

    todoList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [todoList setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [todoList setTitle:@"ToDo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [todoList.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [todoList setAlpha:0];


    [self.view addSubview:todoList];


    shoppingList = [[UIButton alloc] init];

    [shoppingList setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 245, 75, 75)];

    shoppingList.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [shoppingList setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shoppingList setTitle:@"Shopping" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shoppingList.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:13]];

    [shoppingList setAlpha:0];


    [self.view addSubview:shoppingList];

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.listMain.alpha = 1;
    self.todoList.alpha = 1;
    self.shoppingList.alpha = 1;


    [UIView commitAnimations];


}


- (void)pressed2:(UIButton*)button2  {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button2.alpha = 1;
    self.button1.alpha = 1;
    self.button3.alpha = 1;
    self.button4.alpha = 1;

    self.listMain.alpha = 0;
    self.todoList.alpha = 0;
    self.shoppingList.alpha = 0;



    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)pressed3:(UIButton*)button3  {


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.listMain.alpha = 0;
    self.todoList.alpha = 0;
    self.shoppingList.alpha = 0;
    self.logo.alpha = 1;


    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button2.alpha = 1;
    self.button1.alpha = 1;
    self.button3.alpha = 1;
    self.button4.alpha = 1;


    [UIView commitAnimations];



}

- (void)pressed4:(UIButton*)button4  {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button2.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button1.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button3.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn ];

    self.button4.alpha = 1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm assuming no one has offered to help because your code is bountiful for such an iota issue. The answer to your question is simple, just set the buttons to hidden after their alpha reaches 0 and the animations occur, then repeat for the other buttons, not sure why you wanna do this, all seems confusing

Comment: pls see updated/ edited version of my questions and sorry for the confusion, very new here.thanks for any help! Dan

Comment: You should probably just use a BOOL. Or utilize UIButtons out of the box property `isSelected` if you have a custom button